# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' при попытке вывести куки

Tags: python, файлы, cookie

```
def cookies_from_file(filename):
with open(filename) as file:
    cookies_data = file.read().replace('\n','').split(';')
cookies_dic = {}
allowed_cookies = {'ltuid', 'ltoken'}
for x in cookies_data:
    key = x.split('=')[0]
    value = x.split('=')[1]
    cookies_dic[key]=value
return {
    x.name: x.value
    for x in cookies_data
    if x.name in allowed_cookies and x.value is not None
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, что в *cookies_data* вместо ожидаемого словаря находится какая-то неведомая фигня. Во-первых, выведите отладочную печать, например *print(x)*. Во-вторых, а в блоке *return* точно хочется обрабатывать *cookies_data*, а не *cookies_dic*? Есть подозрение, что перепутано имя переменной...

Comment: А ну да, у вас `cookies_data` это список из строк и `cookies_dic` это словарь из строк, никакие `.name` и `.value` взяться тут ниоткуда не могут

Comment: вывожу cookies_dic, все такая же ошибка, как можно исправить?